# GStreamer: activate/deactivate a specific tee src at runtime

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have the following pipeline (important to leave it as descriptor and not build at runtime):

`videotestsrc ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! ... t. ! queue ! ...`

I need a simple way (which is also correct architecturally) of "deactivating" the second tee src before changing the pipeline's state to `PLAYING`, and then at some point "activate" it and "deactivate" it on demand. I'm not sure if activating/deactivating should be accomplished by actually linking/unlinking or by setting some pad's property/state.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I actually had to implement just that in node.js, using node-gtk, a couple of weeks ago. Which programming language are you implementing this in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. In JS, this looks like this:

Adding a client:

```js
const pipelineSegment = Gst.parseBinFromDescription('queue name=q ! fakesink', false);
pipelineSegment.name = `subpipe_${someId}`;
setPipelineState(pipelineSegment, 'PAUSED');

globalPipeline.add(pipelineSegment);
const tee = globalPipeline.getByName('tee');
const q = pipelineSegment.getByName(`q`);
tee.link(q);

setPipelineState(globalPipeline, 'PLAYING');
```

Removing it:

```js
globalPipeline.remove( pipelineSegment );
setPipelineState(pipelineSegment, 'NULL');
```

With this helper function:

```js
/** Set gst pipeline's state to the given Gst.State name, e.g., PAUSED */
const setPipelineState = (pipeline, stateName) => {
  const state = Gst.State[stateName];
  if (state === undefined) {
    log.error("No such state", state);
    return;
  }

  const result = pipeline.setState(state);
  if (result == Gst.StateChangeReturn.Failure) {
    log.error("Failed to set pipeline's state to", stateName);
  } else {
    log.debug('pipeline set to', stateName);
  }
};
```

This is the example (in C++) I followed:
https://tewarid.github.io/2011/06/06/gstreamer-pipeline-with-tee.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want to explicitly include all elements in a single pipeline descriptor.

Comment: I'm sure you can adapt it from my answer. Just parse your original pipeline, break it into the one until the `tee` and the pieces after, and then add them one by one using the code above for adding. Does that not work in your case for some reason?

Comment: Well, string manipulation/parsing doesn't seem like the ideal solution for this. I'll update on any progress, thanks.

Comment: Then, yes I think you want to just unlink, and then later link (and sync) again.

Comment: I'm in C, latest GStreamer, I think the pad should be blocked before any manipulation, also EOS should be sent and only when done remove elements.