# GStreamer: dynamically link a tee while pipline is PLAYING

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

Using GStreamer 1.16.3 on Ubuntu 20, C/C++. At some point during runtime, I'm trying to link a `tee` element (its `src_0` is already linked and playing) to a recording bin which ends with a `filesink`.

The following snippet: create the recording bin, get the new `filesink` element, set its `location` property, add the recording bin to pipeline, sync recording bin state with pipeline, get pipeline's `tee` element, get its `src` request pad, get recording bin's `sink` pad, link `src` and `sink` pads to complete the process.

```
auto error = (GError *)nullptr;
auto recording_bin = gst_parse_bin_from_description("queue ! filesink name=recording_filesink", true, &error);
auto filesink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(recording_bin), "recording_filesink");

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesink), "location", "/home/.../record.ts", NULL);
g_object_unref(filesink);
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), recording_bin);
gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(recording_bin);

auto tee = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "tee");
auto tee_src = gst_element_get_request_pad(tee, "src_%u");
auto recording_sink = gst_element_get_static_pad(recording_bin, "sink");
auto ret = gst_pad_link(tee_src, recording_sink);

g_object_unref(recording_sink);
g_object_unref(tee_src);
g_object_unref(tee);
```

After executing this above, `ret` is `GST_PAD_LINK_OK`, but the pipeline gets stuck - not displaying (1st tee src) and not recording (2nd tee src).

Is this the right way to dynamically link a tee src to a recording bin?

Comment: Check this page: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html?gi-language=c especially the part out dynamically changing the pipeline: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html?gi-language=c#dynamically-changing-the-pipeline

Comment: Thanks @FlorianZwoch, that is my main source of knowledge, I've even managed to remove the recording bin dynamically as described there by blocking the tee src pad before doing any unlinking, sending EOS to finalize the filesink etc. But I haven't managed to add the recording bin after the pipeline is already PLAYING. The recording bin works ONLY when it is linked to the pipeline BEFORE the pipeline is being played for the first time. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932832/1087119. I believe the issue is with syncing the two pipeline segments. The way I do it is to set the new pipeline segment to PAUSED before linking, and then set PLAYING again on the whole pipeline once linked.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Well, the description here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#dynamically-changing-the-pipeline doesn't seem to mention changing the main pipeline's state when adding elements, but only "When adding elements to a pipeline, make sure to put the element into the right state".

Comment: Gee, well, don't believe me if you don't want to, but I recommend you try it, because I'm using this in production and it works.

Comment: Ok, so I've just changed `gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(recording_bin);` to `gst_element_set_state(recording_bin, GST_STATE_PAUSED);` and after linking I added `gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYED);`, but the pipeline still gets stuck.